# How to set the 'from' header for devise invitable invitation_instructions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, devise-invitable

So I'm trying to override the 'from' field so it actually includes the name of the inviter, rather than the system default.

I've followed the instructions here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer

I've got my custom mailer set up, but the problem I'm having is that it doesn't look like there is an `opts` object that comes through that I can modify, unlike the example in the documentation.

Anyone have any suggestions?

```
class MCDeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
  helper :application # gives access to all helpers defined within `application_helper`.

  def invitation_instructions(record)        
    # opts[:from] = "#{resource.invited_by.full_name rescue "Mission Control"} <notifications@#{DOMAIN}>"
    super
  end
end
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to monkeypatch `send_devise_notification`. put something like this in `User`:

```
def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
  if :invitation_instructions == notification
    args << {
      from: "#{inviter_name} <#{inviter_email}>",
    }
  end
  super
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at devise [wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer)

You can write your own instruction. Simply override

```
def invitation_instructions(record, opts = {})
  ...
end
```